# I want to create a purchase order after the "approve" button is clicked on a sales order

Tags: javascript, jquery, netsuite, suitescript, purchase-order

I want a purchase order to be generated when a person clicks the approve button on a sales order. I have the script deployed to sales order records and the event type to trigger when the approve button is clicked. However, this code won't create a purchase order because i have an invalid field value for the sublist item value.

I've used both the internal Id and the string name of the item as values and i get the same "invalid field value" error. Anyone know what's wrong?

```
function beforeSubmit(context) {
    var sRecord = context.newRecord;
    var user = runtime.getCurrentUser();

    //get line count
    var itemCount = sRecord.getLineCount({
        sublistId: 'item'
    });

    for (var i = 0; i<itemCount; i++){
        var pOrder = record.create({
            type: record.Type.PURCHASE_ORDER,
            isDynamic: true
        });

        //get item internal id
        var itemId = sRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId   : 'item',
            fieldId     : 'item',
            line        : i
        });

        //get qty
        var qty = sRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId   : 'item',
            fieldId     : 'quantity',
            line        : i
        });

        //get vendor of item
        var vendor = search.lookupFields({
            type    : 'item',
            id      : itemId,
            columns : ['vendorname']
        });

        //add vendor to record
        pOrder.setValue('vendorname', vendor);

        //selects new line
        pOrder.selectNewLine({sublistId: 'item'});

        //add item to sublist
        pOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId   : 'item',
            fieldId     : 'item',
            value       : itemId
        });

        //add quantity to sublist
        pOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId   : 'item',
            fieldId     : 'quantity',
            value       : qty
        });
        pOrder.commitLine({sublistId: 'item'});
        pOrder.save();

    }
}
```

Comment: or is there a way to trigger the "create special order" for each line item in a sales order when the approve button is clicked?

Comment: I'm assuming that you have tried setting one of those items on a PO through the UI as well, to make sure that it is available for  POs?

Comment: @W3BGUY yes creating a PO through the UI works perfectly fine. the error only occurs at the point where i am adding an item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `entity` field is **required** on the purchase order record.  The `vendorname` field on the item record does not store a vendor record, and even if it did, there isn't a corresponding `vendorname` field on the PO.  This value from the item record is used to identify the vendor's name/code for the item itself, in the event they have a different name.

As written, this code functions at least situationally if the `entity` field is set on the PO.  If you've set a `Preferred Vendor` or if using the multiple vendors feature have configured a preferred vendor there, you could lookup the appropriate `entity` field directly from the Item record still.

An easy way to achieve what this script appears to be doing without scripting for Inventory and Non-inventory for sale items is to use the `Drop Ship Item` checkbox or the `Special Order Item` checkbox on these item records.  Selecting either for each eligible item will allow automatic creation of po's for the line items of your Sales Order.  Search `Special Order Items` in the Netsuite Help for more information on the differences and how to setup either.

Comment: I see. so i am assuming that because the entity field isn't set, it can't find any associated items for the purchase order (because you need to set a vendor before adding items). Is that right?

edit: i can't believe that was the problem. although i havent re-deployed the script, i think that was the problem. thanks so much!